# Project build error: Non-parseable POM : expected START_TAG or END_TAG not TEXT (position: TEXT seen ...</dependency>\ufeff\r\n <d... @28:7)

Tags: maven, apache-spark, scala-ide

I am new to spark-scala, i am trying to write spark application in scala IDE, so i have created a maven project and trying to edit pom.xml file, when i add dependency to the pom.xml, i am getting below error

```
Project build error: Non-parseable POM : expected START_TAG or END_TAG not TEXT (position: TEXT seen ...</dependency>\ufeff\r\n    <d... @28:7)
```

the error appearing at one of dependency.

Kindly help, thru old answers i didn't able to resolve.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.orientit.spark.training</groupId>
<artifactId>firstpgm</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>firstpgm</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
<artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
<version>2.10.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
<artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
<version>1.5.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>junit</groupId>
<artifactId>junit</artifactId>
<version>3.8.1</version>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: your pom.xml is malformed. Share it.

Comment: how can i add my pom.xml file

Comment: I'm sorry, it was saying code is not properly intended,

Comment: Added my pom.xml file, i am getting error near below code

<dependency>
<groupId>junit</groupId>

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that your XML format is incorrect and thus cannot be parsed by the XML parser. You have to check your XML carefully for opening and closing tags. For some reason your closing tag is followed by the UTF-16 Byte Order Marker.

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.orientit.spark.training</groupId>
<artifactId>firstpgm</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>firstpgm</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
<artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
<version>2.10.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
<artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
<version>1.5.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>junit</groupId>
<artifactId>junit</artifactId>
<version>3.8.1</version>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Added my pom.xml file, i am getting error near below code

<dependency>
<groupId>junit</groupId>

Comment: See my answer, the error indicated that you have a [Byte Order Marker](http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html) (FEFF) after your </dependency> tag. The BOM is invisible in the added XML, so I can't really check.

Also, this XML is incomplete, it misses the </project> tag.

Comment: I have added field </project> , 
can you please let me know how can i remove the unwanted characters (BOM), And thanks for your help!

Comment: Try deleting the whitespace and other characters between the end of the offending tag and the opening of the next tag.